# In extjs multiselect combo box how i can put selected value in a box with a cross icon (check snapshot)

Tags: extjs

I have created a multiselect combo box when i selelect values then these are displayed with comma seperated but now i want them more stylish as in snapshot.
[Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVhux.png)

Answer (score 1):

If your using Extjs 5/6 you can use the new [`tagfield`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.0/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Tag) (see the history of it in the documentation):

> The tagfield is a combo box improved for multiple value editing,
>   selection and easy management.

If you'r using Extjs 4 have a look at the [`BoxSelect`](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?134751-Ext.ux.form.field.BoxSelect) thread in Sencha's forum.

Answer (score 0):

You can put selected value in a box with a cross icon by using xtype: 'tagfield', in your declaration.
below is the code example for that.

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
      renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
      title: 'GOT',
      height: 200,
      width: 500,
      items: [{
          xtype: 'tagfield',
          fieldLabel: 'Character Name',
          store: Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                  fields: ['id','name'],
                  data: [
                      {id: 0, name: 'John Snow'},
                      {id: 1, name: 'Tyrion Lannister'},
                      {id: 2, name: 'Morgan Dexter'},
                      {id: 3, name: 'Lannister'},
                      {id: 4, name: 'Silicon Vally'}
                  ]
               }),
           displayField: 'name',
          valueField: 'id',
          queryMode: 'local',
          filterPickList: true
      }]
  });
```

Working example in this link. [MultipleSelection Example](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1b45)

Comment: I have a multiselect combo. When a user select a value from combo then the value get displayed. Now I want add a string in the value choosed by the user and it should be displayed in combo not the selected value of the user